# Swing for apache telnet example

Tags: java, apache, swing, telnet

I'm using this java console example https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/examples/telnet/WeatherTelnet.java for working with telnet server. I need frame with input text field for commands(jTextField) and area with commands and server's responce (JTextArea). I has Swing UI, but cant integrate WeatherTelnet.java with it.

```
 IOUtil.readWrite(telnet.getInputStream(), telnet.getOutputStream(), System.in, System.out);
```

I think I should redirect System.out to JTextArea and jTextField to System.in. Could you help me with it, please.

Swing UI

```
public class ClientLauncher {

    String appName = "Simple Telnet Client";
    JFrame frame = new JFrame(appName);
    JTextField textField;
    JTextArea textArea;
    JFrame preFrame;

    public void display() {
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel southPanel = new JPanel();
        southPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        textField = new JTextField(30);
        textField.requestFocusInWindow();
        textField.addActionListener(new TextFieldListener());


        textArea = new JTextArea();
        textArea.setEditable(false);
        textArea.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 15));
        textArea.setLineWrap(true);

        //MessageConsole mc = new MessageConsole(textComponent);

        mainPanel.add(new JScrollPane(textArea), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        GridBagConstraints left = new GridBagConstraints();
        left.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        left.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        left.weightx = 512.0D;
        left.weighty = 1.0D;

        GridBagConstraints right = new GridBagConstraints();
        right.insets = new Insets(0, 10, 0, 0);
        right.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
        right.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        right.weightx = 1.0D;
        right.weighty = 1.0D;

        southPanel.add(textField, left);

        mainPanel.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, southPanel);

        frame.add(mainPanel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(470, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    class TextFieldListener implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

            if (textField.getText().length() > 1) {

                textArea.append(textField.getText() + "\n");
                textField.setText("");
                textField.requestFocusInWindow();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

                    ClientLauncher clientView = new ClientLauncher();
                    clientView.display();

        }

}
```

Comment: Uhm ... I suggest to do some Java programming tutorials because it's fairly easy to solve if you comprehend it. (the link with that `WeatherTelnet.java` you've shared is an example of using the telnet service. You don't have to "integrate" that.

Comment: My purpose is using WeatherTelnet.java with Swing UI